# date and time picker separately in iphone

Tags: iphone, picker

hii there?

Can I make Date picker and Time picker in iphone separately.
If yes then plz give me some reference.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You have asked 15 question and havnt accepted a single answer. Try to accept answers so that people will mind answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's simple, you can set it through Interface builder itself.